# Comparing the values of char arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have a `char[28]` array keeping names of people. I have another `char[28]` array that also keeps names. I ask user to enter a name for the first array, and second arrays reads names from a binary file. Then I compare them with the `==` operator. But even though the names are the same, their values look different when I debug it. Why is this the case? How can I compare these two? My sample code is as follows:

```cpp
int main()
{
    char sName[28];
    cin>>sName; // Get the name of the student to be searched

    // Reading the tables

    ifstream in("students.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);

    student Student; // This is a struct

    while (in.read((char*)&Student, sizeof(student)))
    {
        if(sName == Student.name) //Student.name is also a char[28]
        {
                    cout<<"found"<<endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if someone has a 29 character name?

Comment: What is the type of `student::name`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming `student::name` is a `char` array or a pointer to `char`, the following expression

```
sName==Student.name
```

compares pointers to `char`, after decaying `sName` from `char[28]` to `char*`.

Given that you want to compare the strings container in these arrays, a simple option is to read the names into [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and use `bool operator==`:

```
#include <string> // for std::string

std::string sName;
....

if (sName==Student.name)//Student.name is also an std::string
```

This will work for names of any length, and saves you the trouble of dealing with arrays.

Comment: Isn't your solution just comparing addresses as user pahoughton said in his answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15050796/433718 ?

Comment: @OneWorld No, it is using one of the `==` operator overloads taking `std::string` and `char*`.

Answer (score 26):

You can compare char arrays that are supposed to be strings by using the c style [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) function.

```
if( strcmp(sName,Student.name) == 0 ) // strings are equal
```

In C++ you normally don't work with arrays directly. Use the [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) class instead of character arrays and your comparison with == will work as expected.

Answer (score 7):

Generally, if( sName == Student.name ) is comparing the addresses.

```
if( strcmp( sName, Student.name ) == 0 ) { 
  / * the strings are the same */
}
```

Be careful with strcmp though.

Comment: You're correct about the reason for the comparison failing, but telling someone to use `strcmp` in a C++ program is bad advice.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in `if(sName==Student.name)` which basically compares the address of the arrays, not their values.
Replace it with `(strcmp(sName, Student.name) == 0)`

But in general, you are working on C++, not C, I would advise working with std::string which will make this much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can write code for your own char array compare function.
Let's start

```
//Return 0 if not same other wise 1
int compare(char a[],char b[]){
    for(int i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++){
        if(a[i]!=b[i])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: The condition in your loop should check both if either `a` or `b` is `\0`. You don't know which of the strings are going to be shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to leave a comment, an adjustment to habib's answer for comparing start of strings:

```
int compare(char a[], char b[]) {
    for(int i = 0; strlen(a) < strlen(b) ? a[i] != '\0' : b[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if(a[i] != b[i])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I needed this for comparing webrequest queries excluding GET parameters.