# How to see if two char variables equal to each other

Tags: c++, char

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
```

I want the user to input two char sequences (such as adc and abd) and the program will tell them that the characters are equal as a whole or not.(the output now would be FALSE )
I am not sure what to do with declaring my char variables.

```
char x[100]{};
char y[100]{};
```

This is my isEqual function to work out if the two char values are the same

```
void isEqual(char x , char y)
{
    for ( int i = 0 ; x[i] != '\0';i++){
        for ( int j = 0 ; y[j] != '\0'; j++){
            if ( x[i]==y[j]){
                cout<<"TRUE";
            }else{
                cout<<"FALSE";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the user inputs two char variables here and then I call the isEqual function to see if they are True or False.

```
int main()
{
    cout<<"Enter first characters :";
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"Enter second characters :";
    cin>>y;
    isEqual(x,y);
}
```

Comment: Your example program is ill-formed. You cannot apply the subscript operator to a `char` object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing the values of char arrays in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050766/comparing-the-values-of-char-arrays-in-c)

Comment: Use `std::string` and compare with `==`.

Comment: "char values such as ( adc and abd )" "abc" is not a char value, it is a string stored as array of chars.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, you have one mistake and one unclarity.

1. Mistake:
   You have defined x and y like this:

   ```
   char x[100]{};
   char y[100]{};
   ```

   After words you create a method, which has two parameters:

   ```
   void isEqual(char x , char y)
   ```

   If you notice, x and y are char arrays. Meanwhile the method isEqual has two parameters, which are just char and not char arrays. So whenever you want to use the first two elements in the method, it will be impossible, because of this incosistency.
2. In this example, I understand, that you want to compare actually two strings. Only comparing the strings to be more exact. As such there is a far easier and better way to compare groups of chars using strings:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
      string x, y;
      cin >> x >> y;
      if (x.compare(y) == 0) /*They are equal*/ {
          cout << "True";
      } else {
          cout << "False";
      }
   }
   ```

This is a simple example, which uses functions from libraries, already existing in c++. You can check this [page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) for more details on the compare function mentioned above. 
Supposing you are a begginer, the most important part, you should understand at the beggining, to be able to use it later on:

- 0: They compare equal
- smaller than 0: Either the value of the first character that does not match  is lower in the compared string, or all compared characters match but the 
  compared string is shorter.
- greater than 0: Either the value of the first character that does not match 
  is greater in the compared string, or all compared characters match but the 
  compared string is longer.

Comment: @BoPersson because of the feedback possibility. You get three cases if you use compare. And in my opinion, that could make your job easier. And  moreover using a method, just resembles a bit more, what the method isEqual was supposed to be. But otherwise just comparing if they are identical both methods are just as right.

Answer (score 1):

Char is a single character like 'a', "abc" is not a char variable it is string varibale.
Comparing char not differs form comparing any other type like integer numbers just use == operator:

```
char a = 'a';
char b = 'b';

bool isSame = a == b;
```

Is same will be false in this case.

In C there is no variable type for string, so you should use array of chars, and you couldn't use == operator, there is a special function for it, it's called [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/):

```
const char* string1 = "I am a string";
const char* string2 = "I am a string";
int isEqual = strcmp( string1, string2 );
```

In this case isEqual will return 0, means that string is equal, don't get confused by this, see description for details of meaning values.

In C++ there is special class for strings it's called [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), also there is a speciali defined [== operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) for this type, so you can use it as usual:

```
std::string string1 = "I am a string";
std::string string2 = "I am a string";
bool isEqual = string1 == string2;
```

Or you can use method [compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) wich is same as strcmp:

```
std::string string1 = "I am a string";
std::string string2 = "I am a different string";
int res = string1.compare( string2 );
```

In this case res will be equal to 1