# compare two c-style strings without strcmp() and operator overloading

Tags: c++, arrays

> Modify class Date in Fig. 10.10 to have the following capabilities:
>
> a) Output the date in multiple formats such as:
>
> - DDD YYYY
> - MM/DD/YY
> - **June 14, 1992**
>
> b) Use overloaded constructors to create Date objects initialized with dates of the formats in part (a).

I am stuck in part b of this problem; For the third format, I made a constructor that receives data of type `char[]` and also creates an array (`monthNames`) that keeps month names, as you see in the code; But in the function `convert2(char[])`, the comparison doesn't happen.

Is there any way to compare these strings without operator overloading, and also without using the function `strcmp()`?

```
const int Date::days[monthPerYear + 1] = { -1, 0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334 };

const char* const Date::monthNames[monthPerYear + 1] =
{ "a", "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "Agust", "September",
    "October", "November", "December" };

const int Date::daysPerMonth[monthPerYear + 1] =
{ 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

Date::Date(int mn, int dy, int yr)
{
    if (mn > 0 && mn <= monthPerYear)
        month = mn;
    else
    {
        month = 1;
        cout << "Invalid month (" << mn << ") is set to '1'!" << endl;
    }

    year = yr;

    day = checkDay(dy);

    cout << "Date object constructor for date " << endl; 
    print(); 
    cout << endl;
}

Date::Date(int ddd, int yyyy)
{
    year = yyyy;
    convert1(ddd);

    cout << "Date object constructor for date " << endl;
    print();
    cout << endl;
}

Date::Date(char mn[], int dy, int yr)
{
    year = yr;
    day = dy;
    convert2(mn);

    cout << "Date object constructor for date " << endl;
    print();
    cout << endl;
}

Date::~Date()
{
    cout << "Date object destructor for date " << endl;
    print(); 
    cout << endl;
}

void Date::print() const
{
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(3) 
        << (year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) ? (days[month] + day + 1) : (days[month] + day))
        << ' ' << setw(4) << year << endl;
    cout << setw(2) << month << '/' << setw(2) << day << '/' << year << endl;
    cout << monthNames[month] << ' ' << day << ", " << year << endl;
}

int Date::checkDay(int testDay) const
{
    if (testDay > 0 && testDay <= daysPerMonth[month])
        return testDay;

    if (testDay == 29 && month == 2 && (year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)))
        return testDay;

    cout << "Invalid Day (" << day << ") is set to 1!" << endl;
    return 1;
}

void Date::convert1(int ddd)
{
    month = 0;

    for(int i = 1; (ddd - daysPerMonth[i]) > 0; i++)
    {
        if (i == 2 && (year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)))
            ddd -= (daysPerMonth[i] + 1);
        else
            ddd -= daysPerMonth[i];

        ++month;
    }

    ++month;

    day = ddd;
}

void Date::convert2(char mn[])
{
    bool month;

    for (int i = 1; i < monthPerYear; i++)
    {
        month = true;

        for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
        {
            if (mn[j] != *(monthNames[i] + j))
            {
                month = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (month)
        {
            month = i;
            return;
        }
    }

    month = 1;
}
```

Comment: `mn == monthNames[i]` only compares one pointer to another. You need to loop over the array and compare 1 character at a time. That's how `strcmp` works.

Comment: it means, when i input June it should comapre J with J(January) right?

Comment: but it doesn't work

Comment: No. As I said, you are comparing pointers to each other. `mn` is a pointer and `monthNames[i]` is another pointer. They point to some values, but you are not comparing the values. You are comparing the pointers.

Comment: @super I get it thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing the values of char arrays in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050766/comparing-the-values-of-char-arrays-in-c)

Comment: There is one answer at the bottom that doesn't use `strcmp` or `std::string`. It's not a good idea to do so, but I'm guessing this is for a school assignements or similar, so then writing your own compare function is probably your best approach.

Comment: @super I want to exercise for myself and with attention to your answers and this topic, i think I didn't understand the c-style strings subject. Again thanks for your advices.

Comment: what is wrong with std::string, or std::string_view ?

Comment: @VictorGubin the problem says that find an answer base on c-style strings.

Comment: `const char *LHS = "Lorem ipsum"; const char *RHS = "Lorem ipsum"; std::string_view(LHS) == std::string_view(RHS);` ?

Comment: @VictorGubin now i get what u mean. i didn't know that there is a function like this. thanks for your help.

Comment: you cant use C++ strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not allowed to use `strcmp` or the c++ string library,
you could either do the raw loop your self:

```
bool string_compare(const char* a, const char* b)
{
    if (bool(a) != bool(b)) return false;
    if (!a && !b) return true;

    while (*a != '\0' && *b != '\0') {
        if (*a++ != *b++) return false;
    }

   return *a == *b;
}
```

or you could use memcmp if it is allowed:

```
bool string_compare(const char* a, const char* b)
{
    if (bool(a) != bool(b)) return false;
    if (!a && !b) return true;

   const auto a_size = std::strlen(a);
   const auto b_size = std::strlen(b);
   if (a_size != b_size) return false;

   return std::memcmp(a, b, a_size) == 0;
}
```

It is of course better to use the c++ string library than any of the above methods

```
bool string_compare(const char* a, const char* b)
{
     return std::string(a) == std::string(b); //for c++11
     //return std::string_view(a) == std::string_view(b); //for c++17
}
```

Comment: `return std::string(a) == std::string(b);` will work for pre-C++11 versions, too. There is also `return std::string(a).compare(b) == 0;` to avoid creating 2 `std::string` objects.