# Compare 2 char arrays C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to compare 2 char arrays but in the end, I made my program useful and now nothing shows in the console, I am trying to use pointers, but I do not know how to use the pointers with arrays, and functions, I think that the major problem is on the pointers.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// return true if two C strings are equal
bool match(char *ptr1, char* ptr2)
{
    while (ptr1 != 0  &&  ptr2 != 0)
    { 
        // zero bytes at ends
        if (ptr1 == ptr2) {  
            return false;
        }
        else 
            ptr1++;            
        ptr2++;
    }
    return ptr1 == ptr2;   
}

int main(){
    
    char a[10] = "pointless";
    char b[10] = "point";
    char* ptr1;
    char* ptr2;

    if (match(ptr1, ptr2)) 
        cout << "They're the same!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing the values of char arrays in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050766/comparing-the-values-of-char-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the statement `if (match(ptr1, ptr2))`, `ptr1` and `ptr2` are *uninitialized* pointers.

More importantly, inside of `match()`, you are comparing pointers, not the data the are pointing at.  And your algorithm is returning the wrong result anyway.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// return true if two C strings are equal
bool match(const char *ptr1, const char* ptr2)
{
    // zero bytes at ends
    while (*ptr1 != 0 && *ptr2 != 0)
    { 
        if (*ptr1 != *ptr2) {  
            return false;
        }
        ++ptr1;
        ++ptr2;
    }
    return (*ptr1 == *ptr2);
}

int main(){
    
    char a[10] = "pointless";
    char b[10] = "point";

    if (match(a, b)) 
        cout << "They're the same!\n";
    else
        cout << "They're not the same!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/Paefdq)

Answer (score 1):

I would change the main for:

```
char a[10] = "pointless";
char b[10] = "point";
char* ptr1 = a;
char* ptr2 = b;

if(0 == strcmp(ptr1,ptr2))
{
 cout << "They're the same!\n";
}
```

Comment: How is that going to help the fact that `ptr1` and `ptr2` are uninitialized pointers?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, you are right. My point was to remove the function match since it does not work...

Comment: This is a very typical practice homework assignment given in class in order to teach proper use of pointers. It is a specific goal of this kind of a classical homework assignment to implement string comparison ***by yourself*** without using a library function. If someone were to hand in something that just calls `strcmp`, they'll fail their homework assignment.