# Matching values from input and from text file C++

Tags: c++

I have a text file consisting of member data. I am developing a program where we can use the account number to match the account number in the program to get the correct member data. But I dont know why, the program is not working, I cant match the value. Can anyone help me identify what is the error.

Content of Membership.txt

```
Mathavan|021127100897|MathavanKrishnan27@gmail.com|0167750575|1410065449|Mathavan1234|3|2022
Mathavan|021127100897|MathavanKrishnan27@gmail.com|0167750575|1410065448|Mathavan1234|3|2024
Mathavan|021127100897|MathavanKrishnan27@gmail.com|0167750575|1410065447|Mathavan1234|3|2022
```

```
string member_login(){
    title();
    fstream member;
    member.open("Membership.txt",ios::in);
    string pass_input, line, acc_num1, password1;
    int login_attempt = 0, count = 0 , account = 0;
    char dummy, resp, accno_input[25], name[25], icno[25],email [40], phone_number[25],acc_num[25],password[25],month[25], year[25];

    account_num:
    cout << "                                          Enter your account number : ";
    cin >> accno_input;

    ifstream file("Membership.txt");
    while (!file.eof()){
        getline(file, line);
        count++;
     }

    cout << accno_input;
    int i = 0;
    while(i <= count)
    {
        member.getline(name,25,'|');
        member.getline(icno,25,'|');
        member.getline(email,40,'|');
        member.getline(phone_number,25, '|');
        member.getline(acc_num,25, '|');
        member.getline(password,25,'|' );
        member.getline(month,25,'|' );
        member.getline(year, 25);

        cout << name << " ";
        cout << icno << " ";
        cout << acc_num << " ";
        cout << accno_input;

        if (acc_num == accno_input){
            account = 1;
            break;
        }

        i ++;
    }

    cout << account;

    member.close();

    if ( account != 1 ){
        cout << endl;
        cout << "                                  Your account not found !!!"<< endl;
        cout << "                                  Please try again !!" << endl << endl;
        cout << "                                  PLEASE ENTER ANY KEY TO CONTINUE >>> ";
        cin >> dummy;
        goto account_num;
    }

    password1 = password;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "                                          Enter your account password : ";
    cin >> pass_input;

    for (login_attempt = 1 ; login_attempt <= 2 ; login_attempt ++){
        if (pass_input == password1){
            cout << "Login Successful !!!";
            break;
        }

        cout << endl;
        cout << "Login Failed. Attempt " << login_attempt  << " of 3" << endl;
        cout << "Please re-enter Password: " ;
        cin >> pass_input;

        if (pass_input == password1){
            cout << "Login Successful !!!";
                break;
        }
    }

    if ( login_attempt == 3){
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Login Failed. Attempt 3 of 3";
    }

    return accno_input;
}
```

Comment: `while (!file.eof()){
        getline(file, line);` should be `while (getline(file, line)) {`

Comment: Also you don't need to open the same file 2 times and read it 2 times.

Comment: You compare two variables that are character arrays with `==`. This will compare the addresses. You need to use something akin to `strcmp`, or preferably use `std::string` and get rid of those arrays. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050766/comparing-the-values-of-char-arrays-in-c).) (This isn't the only problem with the code.)

Comment: IMHO, the class should overload `operator>>` to read in member data.